# Table text vs list text

Tags: table-of-contents, italic

I would like to have the description of the table (and also figure) in italic, but not the list of tables in italic.

If I choose to have the description in italic the list also turns italic. How to i prevent this?

Commands used: `\listoffigures` and `\listoftables`.

All (messy) packages:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{color,colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[titleoc, title, toc, page]{appendix}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{parskip}
\lstset{language=C}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{referanseliste.bib}
\usepackage[headheight=65pt,tmargin=5pt,headsep=5pt,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) showing your documentclass and relevant packages that you load.  In general you can use `\caption[A]{B}` to provide caption `B` with `A` in the list of tables/figures.  However, you are probably looking for a more uniform solution and that may depend on your documentclass.

Comment: This is my documet class: \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
I dont know which packages that are relevant... I have simply used the command \listoffigures and \listoftables

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code.

Answer (score 1):

As you are loading the `caption` package there is a simple solution to this.  Just specify italic as the `textfont` for captions:

```
\captionsetup{textfont=it}
```

It will remain as roman text in the list of tables:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup{labelfont=bf, textfont=it}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\begin{table}
  \centering
  Foo
  \caption{Caption text}
  \label{tab:foo}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

If you have individual cases where you need different formatting in the caption itself and in the list of tables you can use of the optional argument to `\caption`.  E.g.

```
\caption[Simple text]{Complicated \emph{text}}
```

will use "Simple text" in the list of tables, but print the "Complicated \emph{text}" as the caption for the table itself.

Incidentally you should check your list of packages.  You have several instances where you load the same package twice which is inadvisable.  Also the `subcaption` package will load the `caption` package automatically.